# In A PowerShell Window, Ctrl + F Doesn't Bring up Find

Tags: powershell

Based upon this context menu, I would think <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> would bring up the find dialog but it doesn't.  Why not?  How do I bring up the find dialog from the keyboard?

I do see the shortcut has a '-' not a '+' in the label.  I'm not sure if that means something or not.

[image: right click options]

Comment: Worth pointing out none of the keyboard shortcuts work  I am going to guess they are not suppose to.  With the current version of Powershell on Windows 7 the keyboard shortcuts are not offered.

Comment: Not even CTRL-V? I thought that one still worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The menu should be updated to remove the shortcuts listed for `Mark` and `Find`. They don't work as expected. `Paste` and `Select All` work with the respective keyboard shortcuts listed.

You can access `Find` via the keyboard with `Alt+Space+E` followed by `F`.

Comment: Or they should make the shortcuts work again :)  I've submitted a [Feedback Hub Request](https://aka.ms/Nl6oei).

Comment: Correct link to [Feedback Hub Request](https://aka.ms/AA5ne3l), my bad.  Wonder where the correct GitHub repo is to file it there? 

Answer (score 3):

PM for Windows Console here.

This is a known limitation of how PowerShell and Console interact. Console supports several input modes including Processed and VT input.

In Processed mode, Console traps some reserved key chords to perform local actions like Break (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), Find <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, Command History (<kbd>F7</kbd>) etc.

In VT mode, Console converts all keys/chords into VT Sequences and passes them straight through to the connected shell/app.

PowerShell sets Console in VT mode in order to maintain a higher degree of compatibility with *NIX-like tools, etc. Alas, this means that when using PowerShell, Find won't work in Console.

Console's primary responsibility is to maintain backward compatibility, which results in us rarely making any UX changes to Console lest we break something/someone.

However, we're actively building the new Windows Terminal which provides FAR more powerful, flexible, and configurable command-line user experience. In Windows Terminal, if you declare a key mapping in your settings, your key mappings take precedence and allow you to override default behaviors.

If you're running Windows 10 1903 or later, then we ***STRONGLY*** encourage you to evaluate and migrate to using Windows Terminal wherever possible.

Comment: do `ctrl shift f` in windows terminal.

Answer (score 2):

In Powershell / Windows 11, the solution proposed by @Omkar Neogi in the comments, worked for me:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>